# How to get images from iTunes.rsrc using DeRez?

Tags: itunes

How do I get images from iTunes.rsrc using DeRez? I just want png or standard image files. Thanks.

Comment: +1 and favorited. I could really utilize this as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked:

```
DeRez -only 'PNG ' /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/Images.rsrc -useDF > iTunes.png
```

Then run this script in Python 2.x (I tried using the bits between the `/* ... */` to avoid decoding, but it didn't work).

```
for l in file('iTunes.png'):
    if not l[0] == '\t':
        if l.startswith('data '):
            res_id = l[l.rindex('(') + 1:l.rindex(')')]
            out = file(res_id + '.png', 'wb')
        continue
    out.write(l[l.index('"') + 1:l.index('" ')].replace(' ', '').decode('hex'))
```

You should get one PNG file per resource ID.